# How can I return especific value of a static method in my the method that I am testing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mocking, moq, xunit

Here is the method that I am going to test and I want IsPhoneNomValid() would return false so then I would be able to assert my expectations:

```
public async Task<UserResponseDto> RegisterUser(RegistrationRequestDto register, CancellationToken cancelationToken)
    {
        // I want the IsPhoneNomValid() method, Would return "FALSE"
        var isPhoneNumberValid = register.PhoneNumber.IsPhoneNomValid();

        if (!isPhoneNumberValid)
            return new UserResponseDto
            {
                Status = new StatusMaker().ErrorStatus("Some Error Message")
            };

        var isActiveAccountPhoneNumberExists = await IsActiveAccountPhoneNumberExist(register.PhoneNumber, cancelationToken);


        if (isActiveAccountPhoneNumberExists.Status == "error")
            return new UserResponseDto
            {
                Status = isActiveAccountPhoneNumberExists
            };

       

    }
```

RegisterUser_MustReturnPhoneNumberError is my Test method:

```
public class AccountUserTests
{

    private Mock<IUserService> _userService { get; set; }

    public AccountUserTests()
    {
        _userService = new Mock<IUserService>();
    }

    public async Task RegisterUser_MustReturnPhoneNumberError()
    {
        //Arrang

        // in here I want to setup IsPhoneNomValid() would return false.

        //Act

        //Assert
    }
}
```

Is there any way that I can test the static methods which are used in my main function which I am testing ?

Here is the IsPhoneNomValid() codes:

```
public static class Validation
{
    public static bool IsPhoneNomValid(this string phoneNumber)
    {
        //TODO Does it need to be foreign phone numbers ?
        var isMatch = Regex.Match(phoneNumber, @"^09[0-9]{9}$");

        if (isMatch.Success)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown the definition of PhoneNumber, which is what you would need to mock.

Comment: @DavidL what do you mean ? you want the code inside the IsPhoneNomValid() ? but why ?

Comment: Because that's what you want to mock.

Comment: If you want to test the method in the case of the phone number being invalid, set the phone number to something that you determine to be invalid. If you want to test the IsPhonNomValid() method, do it as @HungryWolf indicated in their answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to test your static method IsPhoneNomValid.

```
    [Theory]
    [InlineData("123456789")]
    public void TestMethod(string phoneNumber)
    {
        bool isPhoneNumber =Validation.IsPhoneNomValid(phoneNumber);
        Assert.True(isPhoneNumber);
    }
```

With InlineData, you can test with multiple phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use a really invalid phone number in your case. But I have a lib [SMock](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SMock) that can do what you want. Here is an example of usage:

```
public async Task RegisterUser_MustReturnPhoneNumberError()
{
    Mock.Setup(context => Validation.IsPhoneNomValid(context.It.IsAny<string>()), async () =>
    {
        // You must test RegisterUser method in this scope
        // Here Validation.IsPhoneNomValid will always return false
        var result = await RegisterUser(register, ct);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedStatus, result.Status);
    }).Returns(false);
}
```